# JQuery UI onSelect Not Firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this one out. I have looked all over stackOverflow and Google, and nothing seems to be working for me. I have an inline JQuery UI datepicker and want an alert box to pop up when the user selects a date. My code is:

HMTL:

```
<div id="datePicker1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datePicker1").datepicker();

    $("#datePicker1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The calendar shows up, but when I select any date, nothing happens. I would love to know why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work better if you only call `datepicker()` once?

Comment: Yep! I just deleted the first one. Oddly enough I had tried that several times before, and nothing happened - then I realized I had somehow deleted the # sign in front of the second call. Thank you for your answer. It works now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options are initialized the first time you call `datePicker()` on an element. If you want to change the options later, you have to use the `option` method:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datePicker1").datepicker();

  $("#datePicker1").datepicker("option", {
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      alert('hi');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="datePicker1">
```